# PHP script run once, even on two machines

Tags: php

I have a PHP script basic update script, i want it to run only once, it is running once on a single machine, but when i use two machines and run it at the same time, pressing the buttons at the same time it is running twice, how to solve this?

Comment: Is the end goal to keep more than 1 person at a time from changing the database, or make sure that the second person refreshes to see the updated data?

Comment: to only update once, goal is both to keep only a single update

Comment: So the given answer is pretty good.

Comment: but its not working, i have a field, set at 0 when the button is clicked its set to 1 and prevent any more clicks, but when you click on two browsers same time same second. it checks the field on both browsers and sees 0 then runs the script on both browsers, therefore updating twice

Comment: you say you have "field" that you're using for your flag - on the web page? That won't work. How is a browser on a different computer supposed to know that field has been changed? You should show us some code.

Comment: script checks first before running

Answer (score 2):

There's not really enough info here to answer the question definitively, but I'll take a stab at it.

First, my assumptions. You have a web server with a PHP application that shows a web page with a button on it. You load the page on two different computers (or in two different browser windows). When you click the button in one browser, you want to prevent it from running when you click it in the other browser.

You need some flag **on the server** that:

1. gets set the first time the button is clicked and your update process is started
2. is checked the second time the button is clicked (and prevents your update process from running again)
3. gets unset when the update process finishes.

There are many ways to do this. The simplest if probably creating a file in the filesystem when the button is clicked the first time. More complicated ways of doing this include setting a value in a database or a key value store like Redis.

**Edit** Highlighted "**on the server**" because, from the comments above, it sounds like the OP is setting a flag in an HTML element.

Comment: correct and I have a flag, it updates to 1 from 0, problem is the flag is checked at the same time and it will return 0 to both browsers at the same time therefore script goes though on both browsers at the same time

Comment: How close together are these requests coming in to the server? I would imagine that the server *should* be able to handle requests as close together as 200-300 milliseconds (and probably substantially less than that) correctly. If it's failing when you click on one, then move to another window and click on the other, then there's likely something wrong with your logic.

Comment: when you move to another window it updates once, but im testing on two machines clicking same time and its not working, it is updating twice, i noticed the issue because the sytem is online and there were discrepancies